# How to repeat the menu when String is input in a int field?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a menu below and I want the menu to repeat when a String is enter instead of a interger.I know when a String is enter into "in/nextInt();" it crashes right away. I was wondering what I can do to stop that from where I am at right now.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    do{
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please choose from the following options. " );
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("1. Do you want to use the default rotor settings?  ");
        System.out.println("2. Do you want to use the custom rotor settings?  ");
        System.out.println("3. Start over. ");
        System.out.println("");


        menuOneAnwser = in.nextInt();

    }while(menuOneAnwser < 0 || menuOneAnwser > 3);


    try{

        switch(menuOneAnwser){
            case 1:

                Enigma.defaultSwitch = true;
                break;
            case 2:
                Enigma.defaultSwitch = false;
                g.customRotor();

                break;  
            case 3:
                introduction();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("That is not a  integer.... Please enter a interger between 1 and 2!" );
        System.out.println("Please try again.." );
        System.out.println("");

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of callin scanned.nextInt directly, try to convert that string into an integer catching the exception menas the input is not valid and then set the 
**menuOneAnwser** to -1

```
do{
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please choose from the following options. " );
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("1. Do you want to use the default rotor settings?  ");
        System.out.println("2. Do you want to use the custom rotor settings?  ");
        System.out.println("3. Start over. ");
        System.out.println("");

         try {
           menuOneAnwser = Integer.parseInt(input);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        menuOneAnwser = -1;
        }


    }while(menuOneAnwser < 0 || menuOneAnwser > 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own version of `tryParse` (from C# [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)) which will attempt to parse the input as an integer, but will alert you if it isn't (`return null` in this case), and then you can handle it as a `String` or whatever you would like:

```
public static Integer tryParseInteger(String input) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(input);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and catch approach:

```
menuOneAnwser = -1;
while (menuOneAnwser < 0 || menuOneAnwser > 3) {
    try {
        menuOneAnwser = in.nextInt();
    } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Please try again.." );
    }
}
```